# Is there a method to add parameters and alter them in all function calls in the whole document/ environment?

Tags: function, parameters, pycharm

I want to add a parameter to a function. I have to alter all function calls by adding this parameter in the whole document and environment. Is there a simple way in pycharm to alter them all at once?

```py
def function(param1, param2):
   blabla
```

alter to, at once:

```
def function(param1, param2, param3):
   blabla
```

Comment: anyone who can help? :/

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm allows you to do a search and replace with Regex. It would help more if you posted your actual function name and parameters but using your example, the following regex should get all of your functions with param1 and param2

```
def function\([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\,[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\ ]+\)
```

do
`control+f`
in PyCharm check regex and paste that in.
Then
`control+alt+shift+j`
 which will select all occurrences and you click the right arrow and add your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Change Signature` refactoring (Ctrl + F6 or `Refactor -> Change Signature` on function definition).

Help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/change-signature.html#changing-function-signature

Comment: thats what I already did... but if I control by Ctrl + Shift + F, I still found some unaltered calls... what did I wrong?

Comment: @Emilie It could be PyCharm bug, if you have minimal working example, please file an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY